# Filtering a list during search modifies original data source

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have just added a `SearchView` to my view containing a `RecyclerView`. It works great, but each time I set the filter, it is filtered against the previous filter. Also, when I close the search field, the full list of data does not reappear.

This is what I have in the adapter (I haven't listed `onBindViewHolder` or `onCreateViewHolder`, but they are there):

```
public class AttractionRowAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttractionRowHolder> {
private List<Attraction> attractionsList;
private Context context;

public AttractionRowAdapter(Context context, List<Attraction> attractionsArrayList) {
    this.attractionsList = attractionsArrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setFilter(List<Attraction> attractions) {
    attractionsList.clear();
    attractionsList.addAll(attractions);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearAdaptor() {
    attractionsList.clear();

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is what I have in the Activity with the `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    final List<Attraction> filteredModelList = filter(DataManager.attractionArrayList, newText);
    attractionsAdapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_search, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    attractionsAdapter.setFilter(DataManager.attractionArrayList);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And this is what is in the `DataManager` class:

```
static ArrayList<Attraction> attractionArrayList = new ArrayList<Attraction>();
```

I also have a function in there where I'm adding all of the attractions to `attractionArrayList` after they are loaded from a database.

The problem seems to be with the method `setFilter` as I have found that it is modifying `DataManager.attractionsArrayList`.

Anyone know why it is doing this, and how I can keep the full list intact, while filtering a copy of that list (like I have tried to do)?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
public void setFilter(List<Attraction> attractions) {
    attractionsList.clear();
    attractionsList.addAll(attractions);
}
```

so you are adding to `attractionsList` the references of the `attractions`...

If you latter modify any of those **Attractions** in that method or clase, those changes will be reflected too in the original list..

you "need" to change the algorithm and maybe use a secondary list, that can as helper help you to get a *unmodifiable  copy* of the original list.

Collections class offer, because of that reason, alternatives to generate copies and unmodifiable copies of collections...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: Even creating another `ArrayList` in the `RecyclerView` activity doesn't solve the issue. I still don't quite understand why the list in `DataManger` is being changed. I thought parameters were always passed by value in Java?